# If $A^3-2A^2-A+2I=O$, then $A$ is equal to

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A^3-2A^2-A+2I=O$, then $A$ is equal to
$(A) I$       $(B) 2I$  $(C)\begin{bmatrix} 2  & -1 & 2 \\-1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ $(D)\begin{bmatrix} 2  & 1 & -2 \\1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

*My Attempt:*

$A^3-2A^2-A+2I=O$
$A^2(A-2I)-I(A-2I)=O$

$(A^2-I)(A-2I)=O$

Either $(A^2-I)=O$ or  $(A-2I)=O$

I got $A=I$ or $A=-I$ or $A=2I$ but the correct answers are (A), (B), (C), (D).

Please help.

Comment: $AB=0$ does not imply that $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Comment: All matrices satisfy the equation.

Comment: Is $A$ square? Then you can use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: Yes, @V.S.e.H, because only square matrices can be multiplied with themselves.

Comment: @GauravChandan ah yes, silly me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eignevalues of $C,D$ are $\pm1,2$ with the characteristic equation is:
$x^3-2x^2-x+2=0$. The eigenvalues of $A,B$ are $1$'s which also obey this equation, so they are all possible answers.